# Xamarin forms OnbackPressed is not firing when the back button on the toolbar is clicked

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

[image: When this button is pressed the onBackButtonPressed method is executed]
[image: When this back button is pressed nothing happens]
I am trying to implement a save feature when a back button is pressed, the issue I'm facing is when the back button on the toolbar is pressed nothing happens but when the back button of the phone is pressed the function OnBackButtonPressed() is executed. How can I execute the OnBackButtonPressed method when either back button is pressed?

```
    protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {

        UserDialogs.Instance.Toast("Save feature being implemented.");
        return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
    }
```

Comment: `OnBackButtonPressed` will only been called when user click the hardware back button (only on Android) . In your case you can rewrite the method `OnDisappearing` in the ContentPage .

Comment: I want to save only when the user is going back to the previous page and not when going to the next page, so I don't think OnDisappearing method is going to work for my case.

Comment: Save the data before you call the method `Navigation.PopAsync();`